# I want my old data even I refresh the webpage

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, jsp

**First Question:**

Consider, I am filling any form then I refresh that page,what I want is what ever I fill in that page should not clear not only refresh page even if network problem occurred during filling the form.

**Second Question:**

If I login with any username and password then I fill in form and if network problem occurrs during filling the form then I go to another machine and login with same username password, I want whatever I entered In previous system should be show in this machine.

***Sorry for my poor english, please tell any idea.***

Comment: you should use cookie for such requirement

Comment: cookies are stored on your actual machine, you cannot read cookies from another machine.

Comment: You could fire onchange javascript events on your inputs, sending the data to your server and saving them in db, also let the user know when ajax errors occure, so they stop entering data, when it cannot be send to the server.

Answer (score 2):

You should try and leverage client side storage. This will allow you to store the user data on the local browser. Here is an article on this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

I hope it helps

Comment: that's what I said in my comment use cookie

Comment: Mr.Bhargav Modi you tell me for local machine that is ok. what is the answer for my second question please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing the following requires:

1 - Background worker on the client side that posts the data to the server .

```
  Worker;
  //or
  window.setInterval();
```

2 - A banner or a status div showing the user that he is connected or disconnected.

```
    var isOnline = window.navigator.onLine;
```

3 - Notify the user about reloading the page.

```
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) { alert('Your leaving...') });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first question has a pretty simple and straightforward solution: you'd want to save the data on the local machine, using something like cookies or localStorage.

For your second question, you'd need a much more complicated solution. Basically, you need to constantly persist the view data (input values, etc.) to the server for "safekeeping", since you assume the machine might crash at any given moment.
So your backend should support saving "temp form data", and whenever a user enters the relevant screen, you need to check for such temp form data on the backend, and populate the form accordingly. This will probably cause lots of edge cases and isn't trivial IMO.